# Typescript tuple inference in generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let say I want to write a function that takes as a parameter a two elements tuple.

The first element of the tuple is a tuple of strings, the second a tuple containing
the same strings, but capitalized. The function then just returns this tuple.

I want my function to typecheck the parameters and the output.

So:

```js
capitalizeTuple([["foo"], ["Bar"]]);
```

Should raise an error, because `["Bar"]` is not the capitalized version of `["foo"]`

And :

```js
capitalizedTuple([["foo", "bar"], ["Foo","Bar"]]);
```

Should be okay, and the output infered as `[["foo", "bar"], ["Foo", "Bar"]]`

I first define :

```js
type CapitalizeTuple<T extends string[]> = [
  T,
  { [I in keyof T]: Capitalize<T[I]> }
];
```

Then, the naive approach is to do :

```js
declare const capitalizeTuple: <T extends CapitalizeTuple<string[]>>(t: T) => T;

capitalizeTuple([["foo"], ["Bar"]]);
```

Typescript does not complain and the infered type is : `[string[], "Bar"[]]`
(the first tuple is NOT inferred as a tuple but as a string array)

My workaround to solve this problem is:

1/ Using the generic parameter `T` just for the inference of the first tuple

2/ Injecting `[...T]` (`T` alone won't be inferred as a tuple) into the generic type (`CapitalizeTuple` here)

3/ Using a second generic parameter `U`, to infer the actual type of the parameter `t`, and using it to infer the return type

```js
declare const fixedCapitalizeTuple: <T extends string[], U>(
  t: CapitalizeTuple<[...T]> & U
) => U;

fixedCapitalizeTuple([
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["Foo", "Bar"],
]); // infered as [["foo", "bar"], ["Foo", "Bar"]] as expected
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal using only one type parameter, for instance T ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wzq0Em) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer primarily to *one* of your above questions (SO question posts should ask a single question, not a bulleted lists of questions). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for the nested questions. Yes ! The const keyword into the generic parameter declaration  is definitely what I was missing. Many thanks